# DropDownListFor does not work with ViewData or ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I encountered this error " There is no ViewData item of type IEnumerable that has the key 'StatusOptions' " when I try to use DropDownListFor and point to a select list

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this already but none of them solved my problem.

Say I'm implementing a dropdown list as filter for tasks based on the their statuses. So the FilterView correspond to FilterModel, but the controller is a more generic PageController which correspond to PageModel, so I cannot have the list of statuses contained in the model rather than ViewBag or ViewData.

**I also don't want to hardcode the statuses in the view since they are backed by external service.**

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
public class FilterModel
{
  public string SelectedStatus {get;set;}
}
```

in my PageController:

```
public Result ListTasks()
{
  ...
  ViewBag.StatusOptions = new SelectList (
    new[] { "New", "Pending", "Completed"}.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x, Text = x }),
    "Value",
    "Text"
  );
  ...
}
```

in my View:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatus, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatusOptions)
```

I also tried casting it to SelectList or using ViewData['StatusOptions'], neither works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to cast `SelectList` (type for ViewBag.StatusOptions) as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If you assign `List<SelectListItem>` to ViewBag.StatusOptions then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

SelectList instead SelectListItem

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatus, ViewBag.StatusOptions as SelectList)
```